# @Transactional. What if two users make checkout from cart at the same time

Tags: java, database, multithreading, spring-boot, transactions

How can I avoid the case when two users checkout at the same time, and there is not enough product for both of them?
Users have a basket with goods, when checkout, the number of goods in the store should decrease

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public boolean createOrder(User user) {
        if (!cartRecordService.checkAvailable()) {
            return false;
        }

        final Map<Long, Long> records = cartRecords.getRecords();
        Long sum = 0L;
        for (Long id : records.keySet()) {
            Goods goods = goodsRepository.findById(id).get();
            sum += goods.getPrice() * records.get(id);
        }
        Date dateNow = new Date();
        Order order = new Order(dateNow, sum, true, user);
        orderRepository.save(order);

        Order lastUsersOrder = orderRepository.findByUserOrderByIdDesc(user).get(0);
        for (Long id : records.keySet()) {
            Goods goods = goodsRepository.findById(id).get();
            goods.setAvailable(goods.getAvailable() - records.get(id));
            goodsRepository.save(goods);

            addOrderGoods(new OrderGoods(goods, lastUsersOrder, records.get(id)));
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public void addOrderGoods(OrderGoods orderGoods){
        orderGoodsRepository.save(orderGoods);
    }
```

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
public boolean enoughQuantity(CartAdditionDTO cartAdditionDTO){
    Long available = goodsRepository.getById(cartAdditionDTO.getId()).getAvailable();
    return available >= cartAdditionDTO.getQuantity();
}
```

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public boolean checkAvailable(){
    final Map<Long, Long> records = cartRecords.getRecords();
    for(Long id : records.keySet()){
        if(!goodsService.enoughQuantity(new CartAdditionDTO(id, records.get(id)))){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Tried to do something about transaction's isolation but it doesn't work

Comment: You need to do the ORM-equivalent of a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` to lock the row until one of the transactions is complete. Just using `REPEATABLE READ` transaction isolation level (InnoDB default) is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

let's say the **available item = 1,**
then as explained in your question if two users checks out at the same time
then the final amount left will go to **-1**, at that time check the first user by, whom the available items went to 0, i.e, the first user(check the time when they checked out) and allot the item to him and at the checkout tell others that item selected is not available, and tell them to either remove and then checkout or select anyother and then proceed.

**Note: the checkout time should contain nano second also, to get the exact user for the checkout.**